# Javascript ternary not working in loop

Tags: javascript, ternary

I have the following loop:

```
while(i <= num_loops)
            {
                if(cat_ids.indexOf(parseInt(i, 10)) != -1)
                {
                    catsPie.addData({
                        value: cat_names[cat_ids.indexOf(parseInt(i, 10))],
                        color: "" + (i==0) ? '#150faf' : randomColor({luminosity: 'dark'}),
                        highlight: "#B48EAD",
                        label: "" + cat_names_string[cat_ids.indexOf(parseInt(i, 10))]
                    });
                }
                i++;
            }
```

It's a dynamic solution for adding new data to a pie chart in Chart.js. everything works as expected but one thing. in line 7 (color) i want to set color to #150faf (a blue color) only when i == 0. in other cases it should be equal to return value from randomColor. However it always returns #150faf no matter what.

if i remove that ternary part tand just make it like:

```
color: "" + randomColor({luminosity: 'dark'}),
```

everything works but this not what i want. first data needs to be #150faf.

how do i fix it?

Comment: Need to see entire code..

Answer (score 2):

The expression before your ternary operator, `"" + (i==0)`, evaluates to a string. Nonempty strings in JavaScript are `true` -- even the string `"false"` has a boolean value of `true`! What you're trying to do is to evaluate the boolean produced by `i == 0`. Concatenating it with an empty string isn't necessary.

Comment: I changed it, still not working. first data set should have the color of blue.

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but the first step in debugging would be to ensure that the variables `i` and `color` have the values you expect during the course of the program's execution. You could do this using your browser's built-in debugger or a `console.debug()` statement in your code. There could be additional problems here preventing your code from working as you expect.

Comment: Looking at the answer posted by @Shammel Lee, I realize that you're probably trying to convert the result of `randomColor()` to a string. In that case, you can perform the string concatenation *after* the ternary operator is evaluated, as he demonstrates. (You can also create a string a little more cleanly by using the `String()` method.)

Answer (score 1):

try to replace this one

```
color: "" + (i==0) ? '#150faf' : randomColor({luminosity: 'dark'}),
```

with

```
 color: i==0 ? '#150faf' : randomColor({luminosity: 'dark'}),
```

Comment: Why so ?
Any reason ?

Comment: you can add with **randomColor**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var num_loops = 10;
var i = 0;
while (i <= num_loops) {

  var color = (i === 0) ? '#150faf' : '#ffffff';
  alert(color);
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change that line to…

```
color: "" + (i == 0 ? '#150faf' : randomColor({luminosity: 'dark'})),
```